# How can i send HTTP header with url to stream an audio in Android

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer

Does anyone know a good audio streaming library which i can set the url for the audio file and pass Http headers with the request ?
I have tried the following approach but its not stable it works on some devices and not on other devices

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            boolean prepared = false;
            try {
            String url = strings[0];
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Accept", "audio/mp3");
            map.put("x-api-key", "mykey");
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            Method method = mediaPlayer.getClass().getMethod("setDataSource", new Class[]{String.class, Map.class});
            method.invoke(mediaPlayer, new Object[]{url, map});
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            prepared = false;
        }

        return prepared;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

for header, when you create media source on that you can set your header like this

```
private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
    val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-kruso")
    defaultHttpDataSourceFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty("auth", "token")
    return ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)
}
```